# laravel 5 put not getting the form data with $request->all() and Input::all()

Tags: ajax, laravel, put

I am working on updating/creating records. Whenever i am trying to send data using $.ajax - put, form input data is empty at the server , but i could see the data send in Request payload.

please help me?

**EDIT**

**Form Code**

```
    <form action="{{ route('dishes_update',$dish_detail->id) }}" action="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
           <input name="_method" value="PUT" type="hidden"/>
           <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>


    </form>
```

**Ajax logic**

```
  $('#dish_create_form form').submit(function(evnt){
            evnt.preventDefault();
            myformdata = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                type: "PUT",
                data: myformdata ,//+  $(this).serialize(),
                processData: false,

                contentType:'x-www-url-formurlencoded',
                success: function (res) {
                    //alert(res);
                    myformdata = false;
                    $('#panel_body').html(res);
                }
            });

  });
```

**Controller**

```
 public function update(Request $request, $dish_details_id)
 {
      // validation check
      //dd($_POST);
      // dd($request->input('cuisine_id'));
      dd($request->all(), Input::all());
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your ajax and bacend laravel code ?

Comment: do you send as json ?

Comment: you better to include your code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

change to this

```
<form action="{{ route('dishes_update',$dish_detail->id) }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
           <input name="_method" value="PUT" type="hidden"/>
           <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

try check data before sending

```
var myformdata = $(".form-horizontal").serialize();
console.log(myformdata);
```

Comment: This is not a solution to the question rather a debug hint